# Video not displaying flash video

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-webview, flash

I made ​​a webview to display a web that contains video or flash. but when I open my application webview can not display as flash video player does not support. whereas before I had to install flash player 11 on my hp. then I tried to open it in a web browser on my smartphone, the video can be played. so how to display video on the web using a web view?

Comment: What is your sdk version?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following attribute to your activity tag in your manifest file:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```